# How to open-source both game code and assets?

Tags: licensing, open-source

I want something permissive which will allow to earn from derived works but will require to mention base (my) work. I know about BSD and MIT which is golden classic for software. And I know about CC-BY which is feels like my case for work of arts. Like sprites or sounds. But what to use for case when you git repository have both software and assets? Can I be good with one option? Or should I mix them somehow?

Oh. It runs on Monogame if this is important.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that CC is more suited to work of arts whereas software licenses or better suited for code. For that reason, I recommend using both.

As this [answer on the Open Source SE](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/5737), it's both possible and common to use separate licenses for those two aspects of your project.

It's slightly more complicated as you need to select more than one license and should probably delineate what is and is not covered by each. However, it gives you more flexibility and allows you to play to the strengths of each license with respect to the material of interest.

Answer (score 0):

*I am not a lawyer*. You should seek legal advice elsewhere, but Microsoft uses the MIT license for both software and assets in many cases for samples.

The larger issue is probably if you have the rights to release these things yourself (i.e. you are the sole copyright owner for all files involved).

Comment: I'm sole author of every line and every pixel. Only exception - music. But A) I'm reworking things which is in public domain (composers dead at least century ago), B) I'm reworking it, so it's covers already.

Comment: Just to make sure: _"composers dead at least century ago"_ it is not because Beethoven died a while ago that you can use the most recent Beethoven album performed by, say, the London Philharmonic Orchestra. The music sheets are not copyrighted but the recording is.

Comment: I'm used only music sheets.